# Problem using crontab playing beep sound

Tags: linux-mint, cron

I'm trying to create something like a watch does. The beep sound indicating that an hour has been passed.

So I opened the crontab(sudo crontab -e) and wrote this line(there are five asterisks just for testing) :

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/mplayer /tones/beep.wav > /home/user/cronlogs/cron.log
```

But the beep sound does not play. I tested it manually in the terminal and the beep plays normally.

Thanks.

- Paulo

Comment: Usually when something works on the command line but doesn't work in crontab, it's due to changed environment variables. Standard error might be helpful; try adding `2>&1` to the end of that line, so that it goes into cron.log as well. (Also, you probably want `>>` rather than `>`, so that each run doesn't overwrite the log from the one before it.)

Comment: `mplayer` probably expects an X server to create a window on.  Use a command line tool like `aplay` instead.

Comment: Hello, I followed your instructions and I got the log message now. The comment about environment variables make a lot of sense to me, thanks for that. But I still have problems, using 'aplay' still gives me error, now the log message is : _ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1022:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
aplay: main:722: audio open error: Device or resource busy_. It has to do with crontab permissions? I never changed it's permissions.

Comment: Can you play sounds from two separate processes simultaneously?

Comment: For some reason, when I restarted my computer, the sound started to play, but anything besides the beep sound does not play. I Changed the output sound to "Analog Output : Built-in Audio" and other sounds now play normally, but again, the beep sound from crontab does not play. With "HDMI / DisplayPort" the beep sound plays normally, but not other sounds. @siblynx yes, I made a test and I can play sounds from two separate processes simultaneously.

Comment: Do you have a personalized asoundrc file in your home directory?

Comment: @siblynx no....

Comment: And you _probably_ run pulseaudio, don't you?

Comment: Sorry @siblynx, I dont know what you're talking about, what is pulseaudio exactly? Some background service to play audio? I never changed something like this and I dont know how to know if I'm running pulseaudio. Thanks.

Comment: Ah ok, I should check that. But usually such related problems such as Device or resource busy usually means someone is hanging on audio in whole, like daemon which grabs all audio operations. While ALSA should not do that, it may, when hardware device is grabbed instead of "default".

Answer (score 2):

**step 1**

```
xuser@mbs:~$ env|grep -i runt
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000
```

**step 2** create file play.sh (remember about chmod)

```
#!/bin/bash
export XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000
/usr/bin/mpg123 $1
```

**step 3** `crontab -e`

```
хх * * * * /home/xuser/bin/play.sh /home/xuser/Музыка/demo_moya_vesna.mp3
```

**step 4**

```
$%)) ata-ta %:) enjoy
```

Comment: Nice. It worked!

Or as a workaround you could add a `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000` somewhere around the top of your crontab. And directly use the `play` command without the need of `play.sh` file.

Comment: @AnnShress . in the play.sh script, you can adjust the volume, and other parameters.

IF!!! the sound is monophonic (from one speaker), you need to use another audio player. For example mplayer.

Comment: talking clock (ru) https://tbs-mbs.net/post-745-pg1-sort1/

Answer (score 1):

You probably use `pulseaudio`...

Therefor you should use `play` instead of `aplay`.

Try:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/play /tones/beep.wav > /home/user/cronlogs/cron.log
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a talking clock using espeak.

It may help in your case, if you add the user ID that should play sounds to the audio group (at the end of the line starting with `audio` in the file `/etc/group`).

So add `root` if you want it to play via `sudo crontab -e`. (This was only necessary for me with regular user IDs (not for `root`), but this may differ between linux distros.)

Comment: User ID (`id -u`) is a number. Did you mean that? I'm having the same issue with `@hourly   XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000; /usr/local/bin/gtts-cli -l en "Hour $(/bin/date +\%l)"  | /usr/bin/play -t mp3 -`, where 1000 is my `id -u`

Comment: @PabloA, I meant the *name*. for example `sudodus`, which works for me. Did you try with `espeak`, for example `/bin/date +\%l|espeak`

Answer (score 0):

**Enter the following in contab**

```
# Terminal command: crontab -e

* * * * * su -c "paplay /usr/share/sounds/gnome/default/alerts/glass.ogg" -s /bin/sh <username>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Tom Hunt is right, it's the environment.  And I go with cas and use aplay.

In your crontab file, add something like

```
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000
* * * * * aplay /tones/beep.wav
```

If your user id happens to differ, replace 1000 above with the output of `id -u`.  This will beep once a minute.  For the original objective, beep once a hour, replace the first `*` with `0`.